# Calling of delete after construction throwing an exception

Tags: c++, exception, constructor, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm reading Effective C++ 3rd Edition, item52 "Write placement delete if you write placement new".

I want to how to make the operator delete automatically called after construction throwing an exception.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int i;
public:
    static void* operator new(std::size_t size) throw(std::bad_alloc) {
        return malloc(size);
    }
    static void operator delete(void* p) throw() {
        cout << "delete" << endl;
        free(p);
    }
    A() {
        throw exception();
    }
};

int main() {
    A* a = new A;
}
```

The above codes only output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::exception'
  what():  std::exception
[1]    28476 abort      ./test_clion
```

Comment: If you fail to alloc memory you cant free it

Comment: Delete is called automatically if the constructor throws. By the way this example isn't actually placement new, and placement delete can't be called directly. But if it was placement new, and the constructor threw an exception, it's the placement delete the compiler would call, hence the advice in your book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference: [operator delete, operator delete[]](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete)

I should write `new` in `try {}`. Know too little about exceptions for now.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int i;
public:
    static void* operator new(std::size_t size) throw(std::bad_alloc) {
        return malloc(size);
    }
    static void operator delete(void* p) throw() {
        cout << "delete" << endl;
        free(p);
    }
    A() {
        throw exception();
    }
};

int main() {
    try {
        A* a = new A;
    } catch (const exception&) {

    }
}
```

And the output:

```
delete
```

Comment: Or, in short, an uncaught exception is different than an exception caught at the top level.

Comment: @Yakk C++ is so complicated. Acturally, I don't know why the delete is called only when `new` is in `try {}`?

Comment: An uncaught exception terminates your program, no stack unwinding occurs.  A caught exception causes stack unwinding, which is where the memory is cleaned up.

Comment: The standard says *"If no matching handler is found, the function `std::terminate()` is called; whether or not the stack is unwound before this call to `std::terminate()` is implementation-defined"*. So the compiler can choose to delete `A` first and find the `catch` later, or defer any deletes until that exception is caught. And if it is never caught...